# Importing @types/kendo-ui in correct way without @progress/kendo-ui installed

Tags: typescript, types, import, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I want to import the `@types/kendo-ui` in my project. But even WebStorm not provides me an automatic import function.

Kendo-UI library is already load via `<script />` so that I don't need to import the whole script files via `import '@progress/kendo-ui';`.

I installed the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/kendo-ui via `npm install --save @types/kendo-ui`.

#### I tried to import via this possibilities but nothing works.

1. `/// <reference path="@types/kendo-ui" />`

**Result:** TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'kendo'.

2. `import kendo = require("kendo");`

**Result:** TS1202: Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript modules.

3. `declare module 'kendo' { export = kendo; }`

**Result:** TS2664: Invalid module name in augmentation, module 'kendo' cannot be found.

4. `import { kendo } from '@types/kendo-ui';`

**Result:** TS2307: Cannot find module '@types/kendo-ui'.

5. `import * as kendo from '@types/kendo-ui';`

**Result:** TS6137: Cannot import type declaration files. Consider importing 'kendo-ui' instead of '@types/kendo-ui'.

#### This is how I want to use it.

```js
<kendo.ui.Editor>kendo.jQuery(this.element.nativeElement).kendoEditor({
  tools: []
});
```

This is how it works for now but without autocomplete.

```js
declare var kendo: any;
<any>kendo.jQuery(this.element.nativeElement).kendoEditor({
  tools: []
});
```

I want to use the types as best as possible so without using `any`.